# Calculate the laplace transform...

Tags: laplace-transform

Calculate the laplace transform of $$t^2u(t-2)$$

I don't know how to manipulate t^2 in order for it to meet the form of the product between a function and a heaviside function. Number (27) on http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx

Comment: An almost identical question is worked in this lecture on discontinuous inputs and Laplace transforms. The ever amiable Arthur Mattuck of MIT explains: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-22-using-laplace-transform-to-solve-odes-with-discontinuous-inputs/

Comment: What's the parameter of $u$?

Comment: $u$ is not a parameter, it is the function's name @GFauxPas

Comment: Yes, but if it's the Heaviside step function, it has a parameter $c$. Is $u(t-2) = u_2(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use #28 from your table instead of #27. Then $c=2$ and $$g(t)=t^2\implies g(t+c)=g(t+2)=(t+2)^2=t^2+4t+4$$ so
$$\mathscr{L}\{g(t+c)\}=\mathscr{L}\{t^2+4t+4\}={2\over s^3}+{4\over s^2}+{4\over s}.$$

Thus, from #28 in your table,
$$
\mathscr{L}\{t^2u(t-2)\}=e^{-2s}\mathscr{L}\{g(t+2)\}=e^{-2s}\left({2\over s^3}+{4\over s^2}+{4\over s}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

The Heaviside function effective changes the lower limit of integration so the LT is

$$\int_2^{\infty} dt \, t^2 \, e^{-s t} = \frac{d^2}{d s^2}  \int_2^{\infty} dt \, e^{-s t} = \frac{d^2}{d s^2} \frac{e^{-2 s}}{s} $$

Taking the derivative, the LT takes the form

$$ -\frac{d}{ds} \left [ \left ( \frac{2}{s} + \frac1{s^2} \right ) e^{-2 s} \right ] = \left ( \frac{4}{s} + \frac{4}{s^2} + \frac{2}{s^3} \right ) e^{-2 s} $$